# Cache List<T> returning nulls

Tags: c#, redis, .net-4.5

If I cache a `List<string>` and do a Get I get four items back with their values(as expected). If I cache the `List<PortedNumberCollection>` and do a Get- I get the correct amount of items back but all the values(MSISDN, RoutingLabel, RouteAction) are null, why?

```
[DataContract]
public class PortedNumberCollection
{
    [DataMember]        
    public Int64 PortedID;

    [DataMember]        
    public string MSISDN;

    [DataMember]        
    public string RoutingLabel;

    [DataMember]
    public string RouteAction;
}

string host = "localhost";

RedisClient redi = new RedisClient(host);

//List<string> PorCol = new List<string> {
//    "Hi there",
//    "Hello world",
//    "Many name is",
//    "Uh, my name is"
//};

List<PortedNumberCollection> PorCol = MobileDAL.ReadPortedNumberCollection();
redi.Set("PorColCache", PorCol);

//List<string> msgs = redi.Get<List<string>>("PorColCache");
List<PortedNumberCollection> msgs = redi.Get<List<PortedNumberCollection>>("PorColCache");
```

Comment: Make this an answer and you will get the points. Your advice worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try adding {get; set;} after the fields? Like public string RouteAction {get; set;}